# cx_oracle connection.gettype failing with "" as schema prefix

Tags: python, cx-oracle

I am retrieving data type created in oracle schema with cx_oracle connection

```
obj_type = connection.gettype('EMIS_MILESTONES')
print('obj_type',obj_type)
# Convert the list of objects to a PL/SQL collection
data_values_collection = obj_type.newobject()
```

the type is declared as

```
create or replace TYPE EMIS_MILESTONE AS OBJECT (
   RUN_ID NUMBER(10,0)   ,
   RUN_CODE NUMBER(10,0) ,
REQUEST_CODE NUMBER(10,0) ,
ADDITIONAL_PART_CODE VARCHAR2(150 BYTE) ,
PROCESS_DATE DATE ,
MILESTONE_CD NUMBER(10,0) ,
REQUEST_TYPE_CD NUMBER(10,0) ,
REQ_MILESTONE_STATUS_CD NUMBER(10,0) 
);    
create or replace TYPE EMIS_MILESTONES AS TABLE OF EMIS_MILESTONE;
```

execute type permission is granted to schema

the gettypes fails with

```
Error while inserting data: OCI-22303: type ""."EMIS_MILESTONES" not found
Error while inserting data: <class 'cx_Oracle.DatabaseError'> Occured
```

the reason seems to be addition of wrong schema prefix. **""**
I tried mentioning the schema name explicitly but , the **""** schema pre fix get added even to that.

I am using 19c oracle db.

Comment: Please clarify what Oracle Client library version you are using. You can check by getting the cx_Oracle.clientversion() value. Also, you may wish to consider using python-oracledb, especially if its thin mode works for you since it performs better and gives better error message generally.